# Запись информации в json через время

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пишу бота в дискорт. Захотел добавить что-то типа бизнеса, но не могу сделать так, чтоб он записывал информацию в json файл и потом, через некоторое время, её опять записывал...
Как это сделать? Дайте какой-нибудь совет?

Answer (score 2):

Для записи-чтения json:

- импортируете json
- читаете из файла

```py
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

- что-то делаете с data при необходимости
- записываете в файл

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Для периодического запуска скрипта используйте:

- [cron](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-cron)
- [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule)
- [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: это я знаю, надо чтоб он записовал, а потом по таймеру опять записовал

Comment: @jaxee запись-чтение json привязаны к какому-то событию или просто по времени (раз в час, например), нужно что-то запускать?

Comment: просто по времени